# How does ASP.NET AJAX work when retrieving values from the server?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

If I want to call a server function from JavaScript to retrieve a name of a person from a database (just as an example)... and I went...

```
name = myServices.getName(userId);
```

If I have a script manager with a service reference to a `.asmx` file that has the web method `getName( int userId ) {}` then this function should be called properly and would, eventually, return the name for that `userId`.

Unfortunately, I want to do...

```
name = myServices.getName(userId);
alert(name);
```

however, when doing ASP.NET AJAX, it would call the web method and continue executing before waiting for a response from the server (which I understand is the point of AJAX, to stop the browser from freezing while waiting for data)

I need to get the name back from the server before I can continue executing... How can I approach this to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method you can add as a parameter to the service method that will call the method on success where you can do other stuff.

For example:

```
function test() {
    PageMethods.MyMethod("name", OnMyMethodComplete);
}

function OnMyMethodComplete(result, userContext, methodName) {
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: I do this sort of thing all the time.  Saves me lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a Web method synchronously, you'll need to set up the request manually and use a `Sys.Net.XMLHttpSyncExecutor`.

[Here's an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/06/calling-web-service-methods-synchronously-in-asp-net-ajax.aspx) (see ExecuteSynchronously function).

Answer (score 0):

For a JavaScript solution, you could loop until `name` has a value.  Adjust time-based on latency to keep app responsive

```
var time = 100;
window.setTimeout(name == '' ? wait : continue, time);

function wait() {
    window.setTimeout(name == '' ? wait : continue, time);
}
function continue() {
    //code having to do with name
    alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! You've taken your first step into a larger asynchronous world. I'd definitely go with using the callbacks that `CSharpAtl` suggested.